# Stop all jobs if Server/Ressource is not available

Tags: jenkins

We're using Jenkins to continuously build numerous projects that will all be deployed on an Application Server (Weblogic or Glassfish). Now sometimes these servers are down or unavailable (in the development environment), so all those jobs fail in the deployment or integration-test phase.

What we would like to implement is a mechanism that shows a 'server down' error and stops all relevant jobs rather than having all jobs turn red eventually. Preferably this would be something that could be configured independent of the jobs, so we don't have to add a pre-build-step or similar to each job.

Does anybody know of a method or plugin that would help us achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting out from [Slav](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22839409/34880)'s great proposal we ended up using [Exclusive Execution plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Exclusive+Execution+Plugin) along with [Priority Sorter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Priority+Sorter+Plugin).

Exclusive execution plugin sets Jenkins in a "preparing shutdown" mode, which prevents any other job waiting in queue from being executed by any of the slaves or local executors while lets currently running jobs to end normally. This is performed in the pre-build phase of the job you mark with flag "exclusive execution". In this phase job will also wait till currently-running jobs finish. After that the job will execute its build phase. I our case we invoke a shell script that waits till our main development server (SVN and Maven repositories) is back online. In post-build phase "preparing shutdown" mode is canceled so pending jobs in queue can go on with execution.

We wanted our dummy job to run exactly at the same time backup process of our development server starts, so we schedule it at such fixed time (without the "H"s) every day.

In order to execute our dummy job right away when it is time we mark it with highest priority (level 1, default is 3) the same way as proposed by Slav.

This method has a pair of advantages over Slav's method:

- ***With just one job all Jenkins environment (including all slaves) is halted***. In our case we have a main Jenkins instance with 10 executors to run different job types (from unit testing to automatic building and deployment) and two dedicated slaves to only run functional tests (using [TestExecute](http://smartbear.com/product/testcomplete/desktop-module/features/testexecute/)). We wanted them all to interrupt execution on development server backup.
- ***No job or sub-job can overtake our dummy project***. When using heavy job plugin the dummy job has to wait till exactly all the executors are free, so other waiting jobs can overtake its execution while this situation happens. This is the case of jobs with axis executions (parallel), multijobs or jobs triggered from other jobs (we have a little bit of everything). We wanted to halt new executions exactly when server went offline.

Answer (score 3):

**Without touch any job configuration:**
You can go to `Manage Jenkins` -> `Prepare for Shutdown`.
What this will do is put up a red message on top of Jenkins, prevent any new jobs from executing, and allow any existing jobs to finish. You will have an option to `cancel` this with a link that will show up above the executor's list. Don't worry, the server won't actually shutdown.

No configuration needed for any of the jobs, but this affects the whole Jenkins server.

**Minimal job configuration changes:**
Setup a `slave` on the same machine as the master. Assign all specific jobs to that slave. You can manually bring the slave `offline`. Any job that is tied to that slave will be queued, but will not execute until the slave is back online. I believe there are plugins that allow you to bring the slave online/offline through other jobs too.

You can group a set of related jobs to that slave, and not affect the whole Jenkins, plus they will resume automatically.

**Heavy weights:**
Combine **[Heavy Job plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Heavy+Job+Plugin)** with **[Priority Sorter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Priority+Sorter+Plugin)**.
Using Heavy Job plugin, configure 1 dummy job that will run continuously (or even have it check the status of your servers, and exit only when they are back online). Give it enough "heavy weight" to occupy all executors on the node. This way, when the job runs, it will prevent any other job from running (they will just be queued waiting for executor). Also, using the Priority Sorter, give it higher absolute priority than any other job, so that it will be triggered first among others. Now, when your Dev servers are down, just start this job.

With the above configuration, this will affect the whole Jenkins again. But you can combine that with the `slave` method, so you only affect selected groups of jobs on that slave node.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, the first two suggestions won't fix my problem, as I'd like it to work automatically. Stopping it manually is what we do now, but what we'd like would be for Jenkins to stop automatically, if some given server doesn't respond (or some other similar trigger).
The two plugins look interesting, though, I'll definately check them out.